# Finding repeating values in 3 columns

Tags: vba

I have 7 spacers (1.25mm, 1.5mm, 3.0mm, 3.5mm, 4.0mm, 4.5mm, 5.0mm) that are used in combinations (up to 3) to add up to required final spacing. For example, for a final spacing of 6.0mm, I can choose between these combos: '3.0 + 1.5 + 1.5', or '1.25 + 1.25 + 3.5'. 
I've already produced a table with 3 columns of all combinations, and a 4th column with their sum. What I need is a method to remove all combinations that repeat, such as: '1.5 + 3.0 + 1.5' and '1.5 + 1.5 + 3.0' and be left with unique sets of combos only. The order in which the spacer are put together is not important.
In the table excerpt below where sum = 6, I want to see only 2 available sets of unique combos; the other sets are just repeats of the same spacers that are arranged in different orders.
[table excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwDJ1.jpg)
Hope that's clear. I assume one would need VBA to solve this. I appreciate any help you can share.
J-L

Comment: Is this a continuous thing, something you will need to do multiple times, or a one off?  If one off, with some helper columns and Remove Duplicates it can be done quickly.

Comment: Hi Scott. This is a one-off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table is in A1,

In E1:G1 put 1,2,3

The in E2 put this formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$A2:$C2,E$1)
```

Copy over three and down the list.

[image]

Then using Remove Duplicates on the Data Tab we select only columns 1,2,3(E:G)

[image]

Hit `OK`

[image]

Then you can delete the new columns.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks Scott!

Comment: @J-L Welcome to Stack Overflow - if you feel this answer solved your problem, mark it as correct by clicking on the grey checkmark next to the upvote/downvote arrows.